# Change Attribute of Child Button

Tags: php, jquery

I have to select box. And two buttons. Buttons are disabled. When selectbox changes buttons will be enabled.

```
<select class="form-control" id="target_category" name="target_category">
                    <?php $categories = $categoryObj->deepestCategories(); ?>
                    <option value="-1">Kategori Seç</option>
                    <option value="0">Kategori Yok</option>
                    <?php
                        foreach($categories as $category){
                            echo '<option value="'.$category['id'].'">(ID: '.$category['id'].') '.$category['category'].'</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button disabled="disabled" name="move_category_button" id="move_category_button" class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></span> Taşı</button>
                </span>  

<select class="form-control" id="target_location" name="target_location">
                <?php $locations = array('Türkiye','Çin','Hindistan','Nepal','Pakistan'); ?>
                <option value="-1">Menşei Seç</option>
                <?php
                    foreach($locations as $location){
                        echo '<option value="'.$location.'">'.$location.'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button disabled="disabled" name="move_location_button" id="move_location_button" class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></span> Taşı</button>
            </span>
```

For short code writing i decided to merge two jquery scripts as one statement.

But i couldn't handle both.

Here is my code.

```
$('#target_location, #target_category').change(function(){
            val = $(this).val();

            if (val != -1){
                $(this).children('button').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $(this).children('button').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are not children of your selects, they are children of a sibling.

Use `.next()` to grab the sibling button container, then `.children()` to get the button. Also, working with the `disabled` property as a boolean is preferred to adding and removing the attribute.

```
$('#target_location, #target_category').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (val != -1){
        $(this).next('input-group-btn').children('button').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $(this).next('input-group-btn').children('button').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

button is not a child of the select boxes, you need to select the next sibling.

```
$('#target_location, #target_category').change(function(){
    val = $(this).val();

    if (val != -1){
        $(this).next('span').find('button').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $(this).next('span').find('button').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
})
```